# ubuntu16.04にQt5をインストールしたい

Tags: linux, ubuntu, qt5

Jetson TX2にQt5とQtcreatorをインストールしたいと思っています。

JetsonにQtを入れている方がいたので下の記事を参考にしました。
http://www.jetsonhacks.com/2017/01/31/install-qt-creator-nvidia-jetson-tx1/

ここで最初の手順として、

> ```
> sudo apt-get install qt5-default qtcreator -y
> ```

とありますが、一覧にはない(※)と出てきます。

コマンドを入力する直前に`sudo apt-get update`,`sudo apt-get upgrade`を行ったのですが、リポジトリが交信された結果qt5-defaultとqtcreatorが無くなったということでしょうか？
もしそうならばリポジトリを戻したとかはできないでしょうか？

(※)

```
Package qtcreator is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  qtchooser

E: Unable to locate package qt5-default
E: Package 'qtcreator' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: qtcreator パッケージ自体は xenial (16.04) にも[存在します](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=qtcreator)ね。

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu のパッケージ検索すると qtcreator は **[universe]** と表示されているので、
universe のレポジトリを追加する必要があります。

このあたりが参考になるでしょうか？
https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository

Answer (score 0):

以下の記事が参考になるのではないでしょうか。（英語ですけど、nvidia.comのサイトなので信憑性の高い情報だと思われます）
[QuickTime & Creator on TX2](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1003711/jetson-tx2/quicktime-amp-creator-on-tx2/)